# How to find empty catch blocks in Java code

Tags: java

Is there any way to find all the empty catch blocks inside Java code?
I know there are some tools like PMD to do that, but I am using RSA. Is there any way we can write a regex to search for empty catch blocks?

I am working on a corporate machine, where I can't install new software.

Comment: why would using RSA ban you from using PMD, checkstyle etc? Is there another requirement there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Eclipse Java compiler** can be configured to produce warnings (or error message) for empty statements:

*Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Empty statement*.

You could use the [batch compiler (*Running the batch compiler*)](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm) if you do not use eclipse.

But then you could use other Java tools as well. **Using a Java library is not a sofware installation**. As long as the JRE is not locked by the security manager configuration this should always work.

Comment: This helped me, of course not the exact way. instead of "empty statement" i used to "undocumented empty block". this actually found all the empty catch blocks.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! :) Also finds all empty constructors etc. that may need some comments.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this regular expression:

```
catch\s*\([^\)]*\)\s*\{((/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/)|\s)*\}
```

Where this sub-expression, found in [Stephen Ostermiller's website](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html), matches any Java comment:

```
/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
catch[\s]*\([^\)]*\)[\s]*{[\s]*}
```

This will return empty `catch` statements, but not those with comments.

Comment: Don't forget to compile the `Pattern.MULTI_LINE`. And you forgot to exclude comments in the code block.

Answer (score 2):

Use PMD from the command line, from an Ant script or use Maven to build your projects. This way, you can automatically build and test your deliverables and run tools like PMD or FindBugs.